# I have 2 dataframes. The first main dataframe has a column missing information that the second contains. I just need to add missing column to first

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, concatenation

I am trying to move information from one dataframe to add to the main dataframe. They look like this

DF1 = |Year  |   V1 |   V2 |   V3 |   V4 |

```
  |-----------------------------|
  
  |2023 |  X0 |  Y0 |  Z0 |  A0 |
  
  |2022 |  X1 |  Y1 |  Z1 |  A1 |
  
  |2021 |  X2 |  Y2 |  Z2 |  A2 |
  
  |2020 | NAN |  Y3 |  Z3 |  A3 |
  
  |2019 | NAN |  Y4 |  Z4 |  A4 |
```

DF2 = |Year |  V1 |

```
  |-----------|
  
  |2020 |  X3 |
  
  |2019 |  X4 |
```

My desired goal is:

DF3 = |Year  |   V1 |   V2 |   V3 |   V4 |

```
  |-----------------------------|
  
  |2023 |  X0 |  Y0 |  Z0 |  A0 |
  
  |2022 |  X1 |  Y1 |  Z1 |  A1 |
  
  |2021 |  X2 |  Y2 |  Z2 |  A2 |
  
  |2020 | X3  |  Y3 |  Z3 |  A3 |
  
  |2019 | X4  |  Y4 |  Z4 |  A4 |
```

New to python not sure how to go about this. I have tried merge with no success.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='Year')
```

This will get rid of the previous years and add many x_x, x_y type variables

Comment: You probably mean 2019 for X4 not 2021

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it using map

```
# map the value of V1 from DF2 based on year.
# fill null mapping result with value from the DF

df['V1']=df['Year'].map(df2.set_index('Year')['V1']).fillna(df['V1'])
df
```

```
Year    V1  V2  V3  V4
0   2023    X0  Y0  Z0  A0
1   2022    X1  Y1  Z1  A1
2   2021    X2  Y2  Z2  A2
3   2020    X3  Y3  Z3  A3
4   2019    X4  Y4  Z4  A4
```